# Hibernate tuple criteria queries

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss, hibernate-criteria

I am trying to create a query using hibernate following the example given in section 9.2 of [chapter 9](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-tuple)

The difference with my attempt is I am using spring MVC 3.0. Here is my Address class along with the method i created.

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooEntity
@RooJson
public class Address {

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1)
    private String street1;

    @Size(max = 100)
    private String street2;

    private String postalcode;

    private String zipcode;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private City city;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Country country;

    @ManyToOne
    private AddressType addressType;

    @Transient
    public static List<Tuple> jqgridAddresses(Long pID){
        CriteriaBuilder builder = Address.entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = builder.createTupleQuery();
        Root<Address> addressRoot = criteria.from( Address.class );
        criteria.multiselect(addressRoot.get("id"), addressRoot.get("street1"), addressRoot.get("street2"));
        criteria.where(builder.equal(addressRoot.<Set<Long>>get("id"), pID));
        return Address.entityManager().createQuery( criteria ).getResultList();
    }
}
```

The method called `jqgridAddresses` above is the focus. I opted not to use the "**Path"** because when I say something like **Path idPath = addressRoot.get( Address_.id );** as in section 9.2 of the documentation, the **PathAddress_.id** stuff produces a compilation error.

The method above returns an empty list of type `Tuple` as its size is zero even when it should contain something. This suggests that the query failed. Can someone please advise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so i made some minor adjustments to my logic which is specific to my project, however, the following approach worked perfectly. Hope it hepls someone in need !

```
@Transient
public static List<Tuple> jqgridPersons(Boolean isStudent, String column, String orderType, int limitStart, int limitAmount){
    CriteriaBuilder builder = Person.entityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteria = builder.createTupleQuery();
    Root<Person> personRoot = criteria.from(Person.class );
    criteria.select(builder.tuple(personRoot.get("id"), personRoot.get("firstName"), personRoot.get("lastName"), personRoot.get("dateOfBirth"), personRoot.get("gender"), personRoot.get("maritalStatus"))); 
    criteria.where(builder.equal( personRoot.get("isStudent"), true));
    if(orderType.equals("desc")){
        criteria.orderBy(builder.desc(personRoot.get(column)));
    }else{
        criteria.orderBy(builder.asc(personRoot.get(column)));
    }
    return Address.entityManager().createQuery( criteria ).setFirstResult(limitStart).setMaxResults(limitAmount).getResultList(); 
}
```