# Join cartesian product

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

**Context**

I send some files to some enterprises every week. I need to restitute for each week and each enterprise whether the file is sent or not.

**Tables**

- ent (enterprise)
- wek (week)
- fil (file : references wek and ent)

**Solution with pure SQL**

Make a cartesian product between **ent** and **wek** then left outer join  **fil**. This works :

```
select * from 
  (
  select * from wek, ent e
  ) as t1
left join fil f 
  on f.ent_id = t1.ent_id 
  and f.wek_id = t1.wek_id
```

**Problem :**

How to translate this into JPA (in the CriteriaBuilder way)?

For example, if I try :

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<ResultClass> query = cb.createQuery(ResultClass.class);
Root<Week> week = query.from(Week.class);
Root<Enterprise> query.from(Enterprise.class);
Expression<???> cartesianProduct = ??? //How?
cartesianProduct.leftJoin(???_.file);
query.where(
  cb.equal(file.get(File_.wek_id), week.get(Week.week_id));
)
```

Using 2 "from" clauses gives me the cartesian product but how do I left join this result?

**Unstatisfaying solution :**

Create a view :

```
CREATE VIEW view_ent_wek AS
  SELECT ent_id as ent_id,  wek_id as wek_id, ent_id || '-' || ent_id as id
  FROM ent, wek;
```

Map it to an entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "view_ent_wek")
public class WeekEnterprise {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  private String id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "ent_id")
  private Enterprise enterprise;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "wek_id")
  private Week week;

  [...]
```

Then I can use it in a query :

```
Root<WeekEnterprise> weekEnterprise = query.from(WeekEnterprise.class);
weekEnterprise.join(...)
```

I don't like this solution because it makes me create a view that is obviously not necessary. Any idea?

Comment: Try using [CriteriaQuery<T> multiselect](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#multiselect(javax.persistence.criteria.Selection...)). Check [Criteria Query Joins](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from)

Comment: Not sure but, u can try this. Considering, u hv `Test2` class as `JoinColumn` prop in `Test1` class. Try this `Root<Test1> root = criteria.from(Test1.class);
root.get("test2Object").get("test1FieldInTest2");`. I think it gives u cross join between `Test1` & `Test2`.

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to return from your JPA query. I mean, do you want columns or the Entities themselves? For instance, do you want just the IDs of `ent` and `wek` followed by a (possibly null) `fil` object? Or do you want to return the `ent`, `wek` and (possibly null) `fil` objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the point of doing the reporting-style SQL query with JPA, let alone with Criteria Query.

Of course, JPA (and its implementations) do support tuple queries (as opposed to entity queries, see also: [Hibernate tuple criteria queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554039/hibernate-tuple-criteria-queries)), but tuple queries is not what JPA is good at. Imagine you want to change that report and add more calculations. Wouldn't it be much easier to do that with SQL?

Using JPA for mapping to Java objects and for transaction modelling still makes sense, and thus, your SQL view solution is already quite good, or if you prefer not to store the SQL in a view, use JPA's native query API:

```
List<Object[]> list = em.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList();
```

Or:

```
List<WeekEnterprise> list = em.createNativeQuery(sql, WeekEnterprise.class)
                              .getResultList();
```

Comment: That makes sense. A view would be the natural solution, or just raw SQL. The ORM layer in this case is just a clumsy translation of the actual code that is fed to the RDBMS.

Comment: @AndreiI: That is quite possible... What do you want to say by that? :-)

Comment: @LukasEder I wanted to say that I was the first one to bring the idea.

Comment: @AndreiI: That's impressive. I gave you an upvote for being the first. Cheers

Comment: @LukasEder Indeed, calculations are far easier with SQL. As the boss is also interested into exporting the result of this query in his own reporting tool, I finally chose to create a view with the whole SQL select. Then, on JPA side, I just `select from` the view.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: Yep, that's the cleanest way, and it will cause the least headaches :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have some ideas:

1. With 2 JPA queries. First: fetch the cartesian product of wek and enterprises. Second: take an inner join between wek, enterprises and files. Uses a map (wek_id+ent_id => Tuple(Wek, Ent, File)) to quickly identify where to put the file.
2. Write plain SQL queries and execute them with the JPA API.
3. (Didn't think much about this one) Create a back reference from Wek and Ent to File (lazy loaded) and then you should be able to continue your first idea.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about JPA, but about Postgres. And I would suggest this superior query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   wek CROSS JOIN ent
LEFT   JOIN fil USING (ent_id, wek_id);
```

You don't need the subselect.
The only difference in the result (besides being shorter and faster): You get the columns `ent_id` and `wek_id` *once* in the output (which might solve a problem with duplicated column names).

Should be easy to translate to JPA now.

Comment: How is this solution faster?

Comment: @LukasEder. One subquery less (planing time) and two fewer output columns (data transfer and processing). It won't amount to much, so it's just an aside in my answer.

Comment: OK, I see... Hmm, apart from the occasional cursor cache contention, I haven't experienced any issues with planning time on that scale yet (in Oracle). Perhaps that depends on the SQL engine. As for data transfer - `SELECT *` is the evil part, not necessarily `join condition` vs. `named columns join`. But this is where the discussion goes academic :)